# XLOOKUP with formula filled cells doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of which every value is a formula.

I have the following XLOOKUP: `=XLOOKUP(G3,C3:C28,E3:E28,"")`.

The `C` column are percentages calculated by formulas. This column is designated as percentage and these are whole percentages.

For `G3` I manually type a percentage in a cell.  This cell is designated as percentage.

For whatever reason the lookup only half works as seen in the image when comparing to `G6`: [image: HERE]

I have attempted to find out if the values are equal, which they are as per the `EXACT(G3,C3)` formula returning `TRUE`. When looking at the image this is also reflected, but then somehow doesn't equal anymore inside `XLOOKUP`.

The easy solution for this situation would be to add a fifth parameter with: `1`, but it shows the formula works sometimes; why not always?

**What's going wrong? How do I fix this?**

Comment: Are you manually typing the formula in every cell or dragging it down. If you are dragging it down, I suppose you need absolute reference to C3:C28 & E3:E28. Also F col is blank in your screenshot, are you looking up G3 and below? How are values in Col C derived?

Comment: Try rounding the results in column `C` to zero decimals. Also, if you have Microsoft 365, you can simply do `=XLOOKUP(G3:G16,C3:C28,E3:E28)` and the result will spill down, If not, I think you can still use this formula entered as an array formula (`Ctrl,Shift+Enter`) possibly with the rows locked (`$`).

Comment: @patkim the values are unique and making them absolute doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Rounding the numbers doesn't work either @VBasic2008. Can't try the spill right now, will do once I'm back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are looking for EXACT matches but the values in column B are surely not always going to be since they are calculated.

For instance, B3 has "34.00%" which in plain decimal form is ".3400" DISPLAYED in the cell, but as a calculated value it would almost certainly be something different. An example would be ".340025698532" which would still display as "34.00%" but retain its real value.

(And there's another way calculated values can differ due to how Excel programmatically takes the base 10 numbers we enter and uses base 2 arithmetic to calculate with them, but I think that a bit esoteric here. Mind, that's not "infrequent," just "esoteric.")

So when you limit `XLOOKUP` to finding exact matches, it usually will not succeed and your `""` parameter will be like a lump of coal at Christmas.

Once in a while, there might be a match, but...

In the (apparent) structure of what you're doing, you almost certainly need to make `G3` into `$G$3`. And likely the ranges need the same treatment, but `VBasic2008`'s suggestion to use ranges allowing `SPILL` to work for you would solve that part.

`VBasic2008`'s suggestion to use rounding to zero decimals is almost spot on, but it needs to be mentioned that displayed percentages like those you show are NOT an integer portion plus two decimal places. Rather, they are no integer portion and four decimal places. So when you round, you need to round to `2` decimal places to allow looking up a value like "45%" to work. If you round to 0 decimal places, you would be looking for ".45" in a list of ".00" entries (after they are rounded).

By the way, don't apply the rounding to the actual data, but in the formula instead:

```
=XLOOKUP($G$3,  ROUND(B1:B26, 2),  E1:E26,  "")
```

and bear in mind as well that looking for "65%" in a list that has the value "60.65%" will fail even with rounding as rounding would take it up to "61%".

The upshot is that the formula doesn't `works sometimes; why not always` as you have it. Like a painting of a clock, it never, ever works. The painting is not right once or twice a day. It's a painting, not a clock, and it never gives a time. It looks like it gives the right time, but since it is not giving any time at all, it is not. Your formula, as designed, is flat out not a formula that does what you ask it to and so the times it looks like it is right are not so because it is only the first or second hair away from being a random result that just seems to match. All you need do is use that fifth parameter as it is designed to be used and it will be a formula that will do what you ask.

Well, that and dealing with the fact your lookup value and the values you are looking through are not exact matches. But there are other choices in that parameter and they can take care of the mismatch betweeen your lookup value and the data without bothering to round anything. For instance, if you set that parameter as "-1", it will find the value, if exactly matched, or the next one lower than it. "1" and it will find it, or the next higher value.

Comment: I see what you're saying and this is why the value of the `C` column is `MROUND(B3, 0.05)`, and subsequent cells are `=C3+0.05`. The problem is that this value will not equal the `G` column in the formula as seen in row 19.  This is where my issue presents itself and what I don't understand. Because when I round those values to 2 decimals like you said, (`ROUND(C3:C28)`) it does work. Yet the `EXACT()` and `=C3=G3` return true. What gives?